# Periodically run a cloud function every second without client input

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on an app, where I need to periodically (every second) need to write a new timestamp in a field in firestore, this write should be performed when a specific property of the document equals true, if not the periodic execution should stop - how can I do that?

Comment: Are you aware of the cost incur to "only" write a timestamp every second?

Comment: Yes I have considered the execution cost - however right now I am just looking for a viable solution, if you have an alternative way in your mind which is better and more cost efficient please let me know.

Comment: Can you explain the overall use case. I have ideas and solutions, just to be sure to provide you the best one!!

Comment: Yeah sure - thank you for your help. So the app should be like a game, whereas the user goes on a specific site, where he sees a timer, which is constantly ticking down. On click on a button the timer resets. Currently it is working that way, that when the user visits the page a cloud function is triggered that writes the serverTimestamp every second (client side with setInterval). Then there is a request sent to Firestore to get both the expTimestamp and the nowTimestamp - the difference is the time left.

Comment: Now when there are more users this is redundant as every user then writes the new serverTimestamp every second.

Comment: I guess you need to write every second to prevent cheat/fraud. Correct?

Comment: Yeah correct - and also that the timer works accurately (counting down seconds instead of jumps)

Comment: Hi @guillaumeblaquiere - sorry I really do not want to bother you, but in this case I am really dependent on your answer as I can't move forward without it. If you are short on time I truly understand, maybe just pass me a link or a phrase that I can throw into google and get moving again. It would really mean a lot to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution I can offer is to use Cloud Task. When a user create a session, create a dedicated task queue with a rate limit of 1 per seconds and a bunch of task in that queues (for instance 3600 task per hour).

That task will trigger a HTTP endpoint (typically a Cloud Functions or a Cloud Run endpoint) that will increment the counter.

---

The main question that I had was about the firestore choice. As far as I understand, if you have 10 users in parallel, you have 10 counter and you write 10 times the same thing in firestore. not really efficient.

I have 2 propositions here:

1. Can you use a single counter and have several user object using the same count down?
2. Did you consider Cloud Memorystore to use in memory database to perform your per-user-timestamp-write and save only the result in Firestore document.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer!
Regarding the first proposition, I would of course use a single counter - if this is possible, however I would not know where to implement it, because if I implement the counter as a cloud function the maximum instance duration (as I understand it) is 10 minutes, so at least every 10 minutes I would need to spin up a new cloud function triggered by (?), which may lead to inconsistencies regarding the time. So a single counter is a great idea, but I would need to deploy it somewhere persistent, I guess?

Comment: Yes, you must have a persistent and central counter. You track only when you start your game (to know the duration) and the counter is unique.

Comment: So is there a google service where I can deploy such a persistent counter, which integrates nicely with me using firebase?

Comment: No, But I'm still wondering why don't you use Google server atomic time. It's like a counter, isn't it? You can't cheat it? It count down automatically. It is persistent,...

Comment: I have never thought about that - thank you very much for your suggestion I will definitely check that out! Really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: Would it be possible to create an endless queue of tasks? E.g. I want to call a cloud function every 10 seconds indefinitely. Also, I'm having a difficult time connecting Cloud Tasks with Firebase...is there a document or walkthrough that will help me with that? I've searched all around and haven't found a great reference yet.

Comment: If y ou want to call it every 10 minutes, why don't you create a scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

As you see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref) in the doc, the maximum execution frequency for [scheduled Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) is **one execution per minute**.

Since you need a higher frequency, you cannot fulfill your requirement with only a Cloud Function. You'll need to use another approach.

Comment: Alright so I kind of expected that, even though I wish it would be different. However do you have an idea how I could go about implementing that, as I am wrestling with this problem for a week now and can't seem to come to a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by doing the following

1. Create a cloud function that runs every minute
2. Add in 4 timers that executes every 15 seconds

NOTE: Depending on you logic this might cost you... Don't do this without understanding what your usage costs will be, and don't forget about it. I take no responsibility for servers catching fire with this.

```
   export const my15SecondTimer = functions.pubsub
   .schedule("* * * * *")
   .onRun(async (context) => {
   
    // Some logic (1)
    setTimeout(async () => {
     // Some logic (2)
    }, 15000);

   setTimeout(async () => {
     // Some logic (3)
    }, 3000);
 
   setTimeout(async () => {
     // Some logic (4)
    }, 4500);
   
   });
```